# Get checkbox to render as checked if boolean value is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I have a form working in my User's settings for showing or hiding a part of a User's profile. The form is a `check_box_tag` and when it is clicked, I use jQuery to submit the form. This is all working well. Clicking the checkbox toggles the boolean value from `true` to `false` or vice versa. However, I'd like the checkbox to show as checked if the value of my boolean is `false`. How do I do that given my code below?

My controller action to `update_attribute` of the Profile:

```
def edit_show_hometown_settings
  @profile = current_user.profile
  if @profile.show_hometown == true
    if @profile.update_attributes(:show_hometown => false)
      redirect_to settings_path
    else
      redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.'
    end
  elsif @profile.show_hometown == false
    if @profile.update_attributes(:show_hometown => true)
      redirect_to settings_path
    else
      redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.'
    end
  end
end
```

My form:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "edit_show_hometown_settings", :controller => "profiles"}, :html => {:multipart => true }) do %>
  <%= check_box_tag :show_hometown %>
  <%= @user.profile.hometown %>
<% end %>
```

The jQuery I'm using to submit the form:

```
$(function(){
    $(':checkbox').live('click',function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am kind of confused about your logic, but I guess you get the idea. Just change true and false as you need them. This will set the checkbox to checked, if @user.profile.hometown is set to false.

```
<%= check_box_tag :show_hometown , 1 , @user.profile.hometown ? false : true %>
```

Comment: I actually want the checkbox to be checked if `@user.profile.show_hometown` is false. Also, as a beginner I'm curious as to what about my logic you're confused about and how I can make it better.

Comment: This worked, actually. For some reason it didn't at first but then it worked. I'm still curious about the logic though. Thanks!

Comment: the check_box_tag creates a html checkbox, as you know. there are 3 parameters given:

Comment: the 1st sets the name attribute to "show_hometown, the second sets the value of the checkbox to "1" when checked, the third is a bolean value which determines, if the box is checked or not - it is checked, if the value given is true. Since you want your box to be checked, when the value is false, you have to invert your @user.profile.hometown value. I did it using the ternary operator. Actually you could also just pass "!@user.profile.hometown" as the third parameter...